# applyRouterMiddleware function not found after upgrading react-router from 3.x to 5.x

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm looking to upgrade an old project from `"react-router": "^3.2.1",` to `"react-router": "^5.1.2",`. After updating the package to 5.1.2 I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.applyRouterMiddleware) is not a function
    at renderApplication (webpack:///./src/client.js?:194)
    at RelayReadyState.eval [as _onReadyStateChange] (webpack:///./src/client.js?:168)
    at vendor_fb92231e3a81d6bd9b24.dll.js:401294
    at tryCallOne (vendor_fb92231e3a81d6bd9b24.dll.js:46371)
    at vendor_fb92231e3a81d6bd9b24.dll.js:46457
    at MutationObserver.flush (vendor_fb92231e3a81d6bd9b24.dll.js:172274)
```

This is the code in question.

```
const RouterContext = applyRouterMiddleware()

const component = (
  <Router
    history={browserHistory}
    render={RouterContext}
    routes={prepareRoute(shared.route, '')}
  />
);
```

I have been searching all over for a changelog that specifies that this is deprecated and/or what I should use to replace `applyRouterMiddleware`.

Does someone know how to solve this?